# Querying from 64 bit Excel via 32 bit Oracle client to 64 bit Oracle DB

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

The software we use needs 32bit oracle client. And the PC has only 64bit excel installed.

Currently its giving the following

```
Run-time error '3706' Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? I know both on 32bit works. But need to make this work..

Comment: 64bit Excel needs the 64-bit Oracle client.  I don't think there's any way around that.

Comment: You can install both 32-bit and 64-bit oracle client (each in it's own ORACLE_HOME).  You may need to adjust which is listed first in the system PATH variable.

Comment: Nope! You can connect to a 64-bit Oracle database with either client, 32-bit and 64-bit. But a 64-bit Excel requires 64-bit Oracle Client and drivers, there is no way around that.